# Can't access my apps

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

My primary  shortcut is missing on my galaxy s4 phone and I can't access any of my apps  and I'very tried everything can anyone please help me.

Comment: What is "primary shortcut"?

Comment: @Alex.S I assume the shortcut to the app drawer ("I can't access *any of my apps*" suggests such). // ***Tumeca:*** please [edit] your question and clarify. Also include some more details on *what exactly* you have tried; if you've really tried *everything* already, there's nothing left we can suggest. Also don't forget to mention the Android version your device is running.

Comment: There may be an option in quick settings to launch Settings app. When you are in the Settings app, go to Apps (or Application Manager), find and force-stop the launcher app and clear its data (you would lose all the customization done on home screen or app drawer). Report back the result to us.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a screenshot of what you do see, and ideal if you can also provide an example of what you expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can get back your primary shortcut app by long pressing the app that you want to get back. When you Long press the particular app, it will automatically create a shortcut on the home screen.

Check this link : http://eguides.sprint.com/support/eguides/samsunggalaxytab3/index.html#samsung_galaxy_tab_3_ug/adding_and_removing_primary_shortcuts.html

Comment: For that, OP must be able to get into the app drawer; the question suggests exactly this being the problem and the shortcut to the app drawer being removed ("I can't access any of my apps").